# Creating button with custom icon in sencha touch 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to create a button with custom icon aligned to the left.
I have placed the icon inside

> "App\touch\resources\images\" folder.

I have used the icon config of the button to specify the path of the icon.
On doing so, the icon is displayed on the screen but it is not fully shown.

Kindly provide me suggestions to include custom icons rather than sencha default icons.

```
{  
    xtype:'button',     
   itemId: 'btnHome',
     height: 50,  
   icon: './touch/resources/images/Home_Icon.png',                          
  ui: 'plain'   ,  
  html: "Home"                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a css class for defining images for buttons.

**custom.css**  // css class

.mail-icon{background-image:url('../images/mail.png')!important;width:48px!important; height:48px!important; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}

**source code**

```
              {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'btnMail',
                    itemId: 'btnMail',
                    ui: 'action',
                    icon: 'true',
                    iconCls: 'mail-icon'
                },
```

In the above code i define a css class called **mail-icon** in custom.css file. And used this css class as  **iconcls** for the button.

Comment: I am getting "icon not found" error in cmd while compiling the scss file.Please clarify on Where to place the images in sencha app folder structure and how to specify the relative path of the image in the css file.

Comment: Instead of bringing the icon inside button , I created a panel that contains xtypes Image & label. Later tap listener is applied to the entire panel !

Answer (score 0):

Touch 2.2 or later now uses vector based fonts for defining new custom icons.  I've recently created this new app that will help you to prepare an icons and corresponding SCCS file for your Sencha Touch apps. This has also been tested with Sencha Architect projects.

The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and using the tool to convert Ico Moon project files into SCSS for use in Sencha Touch.

- https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon

Answer (score 0):

Do inspect the button and change the width and height, for me the following css class fix this.

```
.x-button .x-button-icon {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
}
```

when I inspected it the width and height were 1.5em.